# What are the benefits and drawbacks of using a CDN vs NPM/Yarn for dependencies?

Tags: javascript, performance

What benefits and drawbacks do different methods of dependency loading have to a project? When should I use a cdn and when should I use a dependency manager/build tool?

Comment: @Li357 You can use NPM/Yarn for browser dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A dependency manager will allow much more flexibility than a CDN as all the files are stored on your server as opposed to a CDN. However, a CDN can reduce stress on your server as the files are downloaded somewhere else and much quicker than if they were downloaded on your server. Most people choose a CDN for the main reason that most popular browser packages come on a CDN and it does not spam their server with requests to load the file. However, if you're doing something like server-side node.js then you can't use a CDN and you have to use npm or yarn.